# Storing data on lists & need to loop as many times as the user entered - Python

Tags: python-2.7

1. How do I put a condition in my code below that stores the incorrect names entered?

I would like to see something like the below:

Enter your name : user enters Tim

Enter your name : user enters Mark

Enter your name: user enters John
Incorrect names: [‘Tim’, ‘Mark’]

2. Also, how do I edit the code below to allow the user to enter an integer before they enter the name. This integer defines how many ‘tries’ the user will get to enter the right name. If the user exceeds the number of tries, the program must stop.

Please see my code below. Thanks

```
name = []

while name != 'John':
    name = raw_input("Enter the name:")
    if name == 'John':
        print "You are correct!"
        break
    else:
        print "Incorrect, try again!"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do I put a condition in my code below that stores the incorrect names entered?

You can store the names in a new names variable.  To add names to that list, you need to use this code:

```
names.append( name )
```

You should be able to put that code in your else condition.
You'll need to initialize the names variable as follows at the top of your program:

```
names = []
```

Last thing, you declare the name variable as an empty list and then use it as a string later in your program.  You may just want to set it to the empty string.

Your final code could look like this:

```
name  = ""
names = []

while name != 'John':
    name = raw_input("Enter the name:")
    if name == 'John':
        print "You are correct!"
        # Removed break ( as per zipa's comment ) 
    else:
        print "Incorrect, try again!"
        names.append( name )

# Maybe you want to output names if they guessed wrong like this:
if len(names) > 0:
    print "Incorrect names:",names
```

Comment: @zipa  - that break is unnecessary.  Since name is John, the while condition will fail and flow will move on.  I didn't catch that when I copied the code from the question.  Good eye!

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you need?

```
names = []

chances = int(raw_input("Number of guesses?"))
while chances > 0:
    name = raw_input("Enter the name:")
    if name == 'John':
        print "You are correct!"
        break
    else:
        print "Incorrect, try again!"
        names.append(name)
    chances -= 1

print names
```

Comment: It still does not list the list incorrect names  every time the user inputs the wrong name though?

Comment: Now it does, or you can put it inside `while` loop so it prints name each time.

Comment: @Faye Your question was about storing, not printing so my assumption was that you will handle the rest.

Comment: Thank you so much! It works now. Would you know how I can edit my code to allow the user to enter an integer before they enter the name. This integer defines how many ‘tries’ the user will get to enter the right name. If the user exceeds the number of tries, the program must stop?

Comment: You are welcome. If you found my answer helpful please [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/345643) and [upvote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/173400/345643) it. Thanks.